# Error while running a function more than a single time

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, data-structures, graph-theory

The function only executes single time if I call it again it throws the keyError exception.

*Function Call*

Dijkstra.shortest_path(network_graph, 'Delhi', 'Kochin')

Dijkstra.shortest_path(network_graph, 'Chandigarh', 'Kolkata')

*Function*

```
def shortest_path(graph, src, dest) :
    #print(src,dest)
    shortest_distance = {}
    visited = {}
    unvisited = graph
    path = []
    for vertex in unvisited :
        shortest_distance[vertex] = float('inf')
    shortest_distance[src] = 0

    while unvisited:
        mincostV = None
        for vertex in unvisited:
            if mincostV is None:
                mincostV = vertex
            elif shortest_distance[vertex] < shortest_distance[mincostV]:
                mincostV = vertex  
        
        for neighbour, weight in unvisited[mincostV].items():
            if weight + shortest_distance[mincostV] < shortest_distance[neighbour]:
                shortest_distance[neighbour] = weight + shortest_distance[mincostV]
                visited[neighbour] = mincostV
        unvisited.pop(mincostV)

    currentVertex = dest
    

    
    while currentVertex != src:
        path.insert(0, currentVertex)
        currentVertex = visited[currentVertex]
       
    path.insert(0, src) 
    


    if shortest_distance[dest] != float('inf'):
        #print('Shortest Distance is',shortest_distance[dest],'kms.')
        print('via', path)
    
    return path
```

The function shortest_path returns the shortest path between to vertices of a graph using Dijkstra's SPSP algorithm. I want to find the shortest path between multiple vertices, it is working only single time and throwing keyError exception when called with different parameters.

Comment: The problem is likely `unvisited = graph` followed by `unvisited.pop(mincostV)`. You probably intended to copy `graph` to `unvisited` but instead they both refer to the same object.

Comment: Thanks !!! It worked by changing unvisited  = graph to unvisited = dict(graph).